# Prove that if $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \inf \ x_n = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sup \ x_n $, then ${x_n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, solution-verification

How to prove that  if $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \inf \ x_n = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sup \ x_n $, then ${x_n}$ converges.

My attempt:
Proof. Let us define, for each ${n \in\mathbb{N}},$
$$y_n = \sup\{x_k : k \geq n\}$$ and $$z_n = \inf\{x_k : k \geq n\}.$$
Then, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, $z_n\leq x_n\leq y_n$. So, if $\lim_{n\to +\infty}z_n=\lim_{n\to +\infty}y_n$, it follows that both $z_n$ and $y_n$ are convergent. By the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{n\to +\infty}z_n = \lim_{n\to +\infty} x_n= \lim_{n\to +\infty}y_n$. Hence, $x_n$ is also convergent.   QED

Comment: Not quite true for the standard definition of limsup and liminf.  Check your definition and see if $\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n= \limsup_{n\to \infty} x_n = \infty$ can occur.  In that case we wouldn't say that $\{x_n\}$ converges; we would say that it diverges to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to rephrase the same solution.

Since $\inf_{k\geq n}x_{k} \leq x_{n} \leq \sup_{k\geq n}x_{k}$, the squeeze theorem ensures us that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$ exists and it is equal to both $\liminf$ and $\limsup$.

Hopefully this helps!

**EDIT**

Here is a proof of the squeeze theorem.

Let $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$ and $c_{n}$ be sequences of real numbers.

Suppose that $a_{n}\leq b_{n}\leq c_{n}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}c_{n} = L$.

Then we can prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n} = L$.

Indeed, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there corresponds $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{0} \Rightarrow |a_{n} - L| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow L - \varepsilon < a_{n} < L + \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Similarly, for the same $\varepsilon > 0$ there corresponds $n_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{1} \Rightarrow |c_{n} - L| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow L - \varepsilon < c_{n} < L + \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Then we conclude that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there correponds $N = \max\{n_{0},n_{1}\}\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow L - \varepsilon < a_{n} \leq b_{n} \leq c_{n} < L + \varepsilon \Rightarrow |b_{n} - L| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

That is to say, $b_{n}\to L$, as we wanted to prove.

Comment: Squeeze is OK, but this assumes the conclusion ($\lim x_n$ exists). You need to apply squeeze before you know that you can apply the limit

Comment: @CalvinKhor I have edited my answer in order to express my solution properly. Please let me know if there is something that I can enhance.